# Activity crashes on HTC phones, possibly due to WebSettings

Tags: android, webview

I am using this function to load data into WebViews in one of my activities.

```
private void addHtml(final String text, View root, int id){
    final WebView mainText = (WebView) root.findViewById(id);
    mainText.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mainText.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mainText.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mainText.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
}
```

I don't have an HTC phone to test with, so I don't know exactly where the force close is occurring, but I believe it is originating in this function. Do HTC phones have issues with JavaScript or plugins in WebViews?

Comment: Could it be related to the specific JavaScript your executing?

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't as long as I know. I've written a couple of apps that do exactly the same and they work fine on my HTC.

Is it crashing on all HTC phones? Or maybe is it related to the OS version?

Comment: The bug seems to be isolated to phones running 2.2 with the Sense UI.

Answer (score 0):

To say a brand is guilty is only an excuse I have heard NetFlix use. :o) It sounds like it may be due to specific settings of the user. Do you have any consistency in your reports from your panel?

Also, is the javascript editing the 'text' object?